# Having problems running a Visual Basic code in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

> Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target
> C:\Users\varad\source\repos\Project3\Project3\bin\Debug\Project3.ex e'
> is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set in OutputPath
> and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct
> location for the target assembly

The error above is given after starting the program. I am using windows 10. I tried adding Project3.exe file in the debug folder but it is not working.

Comment: What changed between when it last worked, and now? Is your project building currently? Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: I would suggest deleting the bin and obj folders and trying again.

Comment: Not sure if this will have anything to do with your problem, but is the space intentional? `...\Project3.ex e`

Comment: Why was this tagged VB6?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure that output path of project is correct (Project > Properties > Build > Output path).
2. Go to Build > Configuration Manager, and make sure the project has selected the Build.
3. Rebuild the project.